# How do I create a visual and/or auditory indication that an inverter has switched off and the mains are back on?

Tags: power-supply, mains, inverter

**EDIT**

I came to know that o/p of inverter is AC. I apologize if I sounded silly previously. To be more specific,

How do I create

- a visual indication
- an audio indication

in my living room such that a bulb switches on when the inverter works and switches off when the mains work and also if possible hear a beep or a string of beeps in my living room to know when the inverter has switched off and the mains are back on?

---

My first question in electronics SE.

I have an inverter at home, India. It always beeps 4 times when the power goes out and it switches on. But, when the main line comes back on, there is no beep or indication except the small LED on it. It'd be really useful/helpful if something can be done to let a person (my parents and grandparents at home) know that the main is back on and the power is running on the mains and not the inverter. It is kind of painful for them to go check out whether or not the power has come back every single time, because of its location and because of the frequency of power cuts here. The inverter is a basic one (supports just one fan and light), so they need to check so that they can run essential items like mixer, washing machine, etc. when the power comes back.

Are there any ideas or suggestions as to how I can proceed or what I can do? I thought of two ideas, one is a simple beep (or multiple beeps) and the other is a bulb (a small one) situated at a comfortable place in the living room which can switch on when the power is on the inverter and switch off when it is running on the mains. I don't exactly know how to proceed or what to do here.

NOTE: I don't want to touch the inverter for any purpose here because if I screw up then it'd be an additional expense to call someone to fix it.

Comment: What is the inverter connected to in your house?

Comment: @Andyaka Well, it is connected to the entire supply at home except the 15amp outlets.

Comment: Have a buzzer connected to the 15A sockets that runs for a short time and maybe flashes a lamp.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes I did think of that. It so happens that the house is in '3 phase' and the 15A is in a different phase and the remaining house is in two phases. So apparently, the different phases get cut off at different times. And that makes it difficult to see where to create the things that I want ie. I need to put it in such a way that I can do something in relation to the two phases connected to the inverter. (Pls forgive me, I don't know much about 'phase' and many other tech terms)